# How to implement a simple box plot chart with javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, progress-bar, vue-composition-api

I want to implement a chart like below.

[image]

But my problem is collision of the numbers in this chart and I couldn't find a suitable solution for this. For example when two or three values are very close together, the collision happens. (the image below)

[image]

```html
<template>
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <div class="box" style="width: 100%">
      <div :style="{ left: `${bound1.spaceLeft}%` }" class="box__q1-line" />
      <div :style="{ left: `${bound2.spaceLeft}%` }" class="box__q2-line" />
      <div :style="{ width: `${theValue.width}%` }" class="box__value" />
    </div>
    <div class="box__values-container">
      <div
        v-for="(item, i) in sorted"
        :key="i"
        class="box__amount"
        :style="{ left: `${item.spaceLeft}%` }"
      >
        {{ item.realValue }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from "@vue/composition-api";

  function round(number: number) {
    return Math.floor(number * 1000) / 1000;
  }

  export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {
      const bound1 = ref({
        realValue: 0,
        spaceLeft: 0,
      });
      const bound2 = ref({
        realValue: 0,
        spaceLeft: 0,
      });
      const theValue = ref({
        realValue: 0,
        spaceLeft: 0,
        width: 0,
      });

      const eachWidth = 6;
      type ChartData = { realValue: number; spaceLeft: number };

      const sorted = ref<Array<ChartData>>();

      function compare(obj1: ChartData, obj2: ChartData) {
        if (obj1.spaceLeft < obj2.spaceLeft) return -1;
        if (obj1.spaceLeft > obj2.spaceLeft) return 1;
        return 0;
      }

      watch(
        props,
        () => {
          bound1.value.realValue = props.q1!;
          bound2.value.realValue = props.q2!;
          theValue.value.realValue = props.value!;

          bound1.value.spaceLeft = round((props.q1! / props.max!) * 100);
          bound2.value.spaceLeft = round((props.q2! / props.max!) * 100);
          theValue.value.spaceLeft = round((props.value! / props.max!) * 100);
          theValue.value.width = round((props.value! / props.max!) * 100);

          sorted.value = [bound1.value, bound2.value, theValue.value].sort(
            compare
          );
          if (
            sorted.value[1].spaceLeft + eachWidth >
            sorted.value[2].spaceLeft
          ) {
            sorted.value[1].spaceLeft = sorted.value[2].spaceLeft - eachWidth;
          }
          if (
            sorted.value[0].spaceLeft + eachWidth >
            sorted.value[1].spaceLeft
          ) {
            sorted.value[0].spaceLeft = sorted.value[1].spaceLeft - eachWidth;
          }

          if (theValue.value.width < 0) theValue.value.width = 3;
          if (bound1.value.spaceLeft < 0) bound1.value.spaceLeft = 3;
          if (bound2.value.spaceLeft < 0) bound2.value.spaceLeft = 3;
        },
        { deep: true, immediate: true }
      );

      return {
        bound1,
        bound2,
        theValue,
        sorted,
      };
    },
    props: {
      q1: {
        type: Number,
      },
      q2: {
        type: Number,
      },
      max: {
        type: Number,
      },
      value: {
        type: Number,
      },
    },
  });
</script>

<style>
  .box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: #b8d0de;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .box__q1-line,
  .box__q2-line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .box__value {
    background: #3c8dbc;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .box__amount {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    bottom: -25px;
  }
  .box__values-container {
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
```

I considered two thin `div`s with absolute position for the two lines and I set the `left` property of them according to their values and another `div` for the amount and I set the width of it according to its value.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70228095/edit) and share some of your code such that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I will be grateful if you can implement this (with html/css/js) from the ground up, because I did this in such a dirty way :))

Comment: Why would you have someone build something from the ground up when you have something that seems to clearly work? Dirty code can be cleaned up (please share and be willing to accept constructive criticism). Working code in particular can be reviewed by others at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @phentnil Please don't refer to Code Review on questions with code which doesn't work as intended. Users can easily misunderstand you direction to CR as telling users to post off-topic questions on CR.

Comment: We have yet to determine that this code isn't working. If the code is just "dirty" CR would be more appropriate, no?

Comment: Thank you about your opinions. I added working code example.

Comment: Perhaps you could implement the current value on the top of the bar? In this way collision will never happen.

Comment: Unfortunately the client doesn't want this and I have to implement that in this way. Although, if I do as you say, the two lines still could collapse together.